# Assigning attributedText to UILabel crashes app with 'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsattributedstring

This is the implementation of code of my tableViewCell, what I am doing here is simply getting the Data from my MainViewController and assign it to two different UILabels.

The issue resides in the UILabel *subTitle, when I assign it using attributedText in order to pass the desired line spacing, the app crashes after I scroll the tableView. But if I simply assign it with a .text = it runs fine, no crash.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *subTitle;

- (void)configureWithPosts:(Data *)data {

  self.title.text = data.title;

  NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:data.excerpt];
  NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
  [attributeString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
  [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:3];

  self.subTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:102.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
  self.subTitle.attributedText = attributeString;

}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:: nil value'
```

Comment: Can you debug and check What is the value in `data.excerpt` is that nil?

Comment: no It's not, the app runs fine and I can see in the device the desired effect, it is only after I give it a long scroll that it crashes =/

Comment: Is this method called from cellForRowAtIndexPath. I guess so, because initial set of object seems to have valid data and when you scroll the table view loads other cells, where the data is nil

Comment: yes you are correct the this method is called from cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: put a break point and log the value of `data.excerpt` and see, whether there is a value in all cases.

Comment: Alternatively remove ` NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:data.excerpt];' use these two lines., `NSString *subtitle = data.excerpt? data.excerpt:@" ";
         NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:subtitle];` and see whether you are getting crash

Comment: Since you don't "really" modify the string, try to do do: `setAttributedText:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.title.text attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}];`

Comment: @Larme I tried what you said and it seems to partially solve the issue, the thing is I have a UITableView with 250 articles in it and over time this number will grow automatically whenever the user fetches new data. For starters I tried with the initial 250 items and it did not crash, but when I up the number to 500 cells it crashes (I am not getting any memory warning or anything related it is just the initial thread error) =/

Comment: Check if  `self.title.text` is not nil before configuring. With the lazy loading of the `UITableView` it may cause an issue.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this error while accidentally attempting to set the font to something that didn't exist:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *selectedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.allUsersButton.titleLabel.text];
[selectedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] range:NSMakeRange(0, selectedString.length)];
[selectedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue-Bold" size:16.0f]
```

The issue here is that the NSFontAttributeName should be `fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue-Bold"`

Comment: Am I missing something? That's exactly what your attribute is in the code snippet! Editorial error?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before too, it seems like it's a bug in `UILabel` on iOS7.

I switched to using `TTTAttributedLabel` here https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel and I haven't seen any issue like this since.

Answer (score -1):

The error is saying that the string **data.excerpt** is nil in the line

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:data.excerpt];
```

I'm guessing you really wanted **data.title**. But that's just a guess with out the rest of your code.

Comment: I don't think so, because the title is already set and this is used for subtitle.

Comment: data.excerpt is another valid NSString inside my Data.h model =)